# What is the format of ip address in kibana that i want to see ip distribution in map?

Tags: dictionary, elasticsearch, kibana

Recently, I'm developing with elasticsearch and kibana.

Now, I want to see IP distribution in map, but I do not know the IP format, my example.json shows below which can not be identified in kibana map :

```
 {"index":{"_index":"json","_type":"column","_id":126245}}
{"@timestamp": "2014-01-11T19:38:56.573Z","column_id":126246,"play_name":"A Winters Tale","speech_number":38,"column_number":"","client_ip":"199.72.81.55","text_entry":"Exeunt"}
```

And my JSON schema likes this :

```
  {
 "mappings" : {
  "_default_" : {
   "properties" : {
    "client_ip" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "play_name" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed" },
    "line_id" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "speech_number" : { "type" : "integer" },
    "@timestamp" : {"type" : "date", "format" : "dateOptionalTime"}
   }
  }
 }
}
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the map panel in kibana you need to add `geoip` data to your rows.  You can do this manually or with something like [logstash's geoip filter](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/geoip)

There is at least one good blog post I've found with just googling `kibana map geoip` (although some of the steps in it aren't necessary with the most recent versions of kibana.